# $ajax webservice failing on webfarm scenario

Tags: javascript, ajax, webforms

I am working on asp.net web form project.
In particular scenario I want to set some session values when user check/uncheck checkboxes in javascript.
In JavaScript session is not accessible so I developed a web service and gives call the web service method and that web method will going to set the values to session.
here is my js web service call.

$.ajax({
            async: false,
            url: baseUrl + '/' + "WebServices/ExtraInfoWebService.asmx/MyWebMethod",
            data: { hdnValue: $("[id$='hdnCCSarray']").val() },
            success: gett
        });

This webservice call works perfectly on development machine having single IIS server but fails on production environment where multiple  IIS boxes. I observed carefully and found that this webservice call is not working on IE browser only.
Anyone has suggestion on this please let me know.

Thanks in Advance!!!

Answer (score 0):

If you are running in a Web Farm this means that you cannot use the default session store mode (InProc) because the different nodes of the farm will not be able to synchronize the session values. You will need to use an out-of-process session mode. There are 2 available:

- StateServer
- SQLServer

You can read more about the different session state modes in [`this MSDN article`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178586%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

Or even better: refactor your code so that it doesn't rely on any session at all. I find it a very bad design to have a web service which is not stateless.

Comment: Then the problem is somewhere else and probably unrelated to the session at all. You could use Fiddler to see what exactly is being sent over the wire during the AJAX request and see why it is failing.

Comment: I have created on table where i keep sessionid and session values. instead of putting values i use to put values in that tables.. in this way i figure out there was a problem in web service call. in IE browser only. session id and session is prefectly fine.